# Jetpack compose - Having two text that fill parent and align from start like table view

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have table view like this in compose. I used Columns with row in this way. But the thing is I can not make text fill all parent even by wight and text alignment from start they did not pos from start.

[image]

But result is nit aligned from start.

```
Column {
pairs.forEach {
        Row {
               Text(it.first, Modifier.weight(1f).background(Color.Blue), textAlign = TextAlign.Start)
               Text(it.second, Modifier.weight(1f), textAlign = TextAlign.Start)
           }
      }
```

Every thing seems fine with this code but result is here:
[image]

I put background color as blue to see that if really text fill parent or not. But seems that it will not fill parent and weight is not woking here.

Comment: Your code should work. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For compose version 1.0.0-alpha04, its works fine, but for version 1.0.0-alpha05, Instead of `TextAlign.Start` we need to give `TextAlign.Justify` to get the expected result.

As per doc

```
/**
 * Stretch lines of text that end with a soft line break to fill the width of
 * the container.
 *
 * Lines that end with hard line breaks are aligned towards the [Start] edge.
 */
Justify,

/**
 * Align the text on the leading edge of the container.
 *
 * For Left to Right text ([ResolvedTextDirection.Ltr]), this is the left edge.
 *
 * For Right to Left text ([ResolvedTextDirection.Rtl]), like Arabic, this is the right edge.
 */
Start,
```

But I am not sure why `TextAlign.Start` it's working in aplha4 and aplha5